# How can I make Excel like grid in asp.net C# Webform

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datagridview, webforms

How can I make a grid like in Excel in ASP.NET WebForms?

I would like rows and columns where user can enter data and after a click on a save button the data would be inserted into a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you out to full-fill your requirement.Here I am giving only aspx and  c# coding. Create and modify your database and change the code accordingly.Here I am using direct insert statement you can use stored procedure.

Table in Database:-

[image]

page.aspx :-

```
<asp:GridView ID="excelgrd" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Slno" HeaderText="SL No" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txnm" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txdesc" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                      <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                      <FooterTemplate>
                       <asp:Button ID="ButtonAdd" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" OnClick="ButtonAdd_Click" />
                      </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:Button ID="svbtn" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="svbtn_Click" />`
```

code behind of your page :-

`

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ToString());
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!IsPostBack)
        {
             bindgrd();//bind your grid
        }
    }
    private void bindgrd()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Slno", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Desc", typeof(string)));
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["Slno"] = 1;
        dr["Name"] = string.Empty;
        dr["Desc"] = string.Empty;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //Store the DataTable in ViewState
        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dt;
        excelgrd.DataSource = dt;
        excelgrd.DataBind();
    }
    protected void addnewrow()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    //extract the TextBox values
                    TextBox tx1 = (TextBox)excelgrd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txnm");
                    TextBox tx2 = (TextBox)excelgrd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txdesc");

                    drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                    drCurrentRow["Slno"] = i + 1;

                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Name"] = tx1.Text;
                    dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Desc"] = tx2.Text;

                    rowIndex++;
                }
                dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                excelgrd.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                excelgrd.DataBind();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("ViewState is null");
        }

        //Set Previous Data on Postbacks
        SetPreviousData();
    }
    private void SetPreviousData()
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;
        if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    TextBox tx1 = (TextBox)excelgrd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txnm");
                    TextBox tx2 = (TextBox)excelgrd.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("txdesc");
                    tx1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                    tx2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["Desc"].ToString();

                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void svbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(GridViewRow r in excelgrd.Rows)
        {
          string des =(r.FindControl("txdesc") as TextBox).Text;
          string nm = (r.FindControl("txnm") as TextBox).Text;
          try
          {
              con.Open();
              SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("insert into test (name,name_desc) values('"+nm+"','"+des+"')", con);
              sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
              sql.Dispose();
          }
          catch (Exception e1)
          {
              string error = e1.ToString();
          }
          finally
          {
              con.Close();

          }

        }
    }
    protected void ButtonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        addnewrow();
    }`
```

Comment: Thanks Bro its very helping now i just want to ask one thing more is i can store different rows data against one id

Comment: You welcome. Yes ,you can store data against one id, here slno from gridview is not saved on table. Table have an auto-generate column id. One thing I am a female user.

Comment: thanks so much for this. But if I we're to use a checkbox instead of textbox?in the code at addnewrow() , svbtn_Click, and SetPreviousData() , what commands should be used to replace the .Text, .ToString, etc. Hope you can help me thanks

Comment: So For `CheckBox` your **Column Type** will be `bool` and in `addnewrow() , svbtn_Click, and SetPreviousData()` , use  `.checked`. Hope you understand what will be the changes. If not comment again.

Comment: glad you replied! so in binding the data to grid, i changed the **string to bool** `dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Active", typeof(bool)));` but what to replace the **string** here `dr["Active"] = string.Empty;` ? then in `addnewrow() , dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Active"] = ck1.Checked;` but how about in SetPreviousData() ?? i dont know what to add here after the dot  `ck1.Checked = dt.Rows[i]["Active"]`.

Comment: So `dr["Active"] = false;` will be false for first time and in **SetPreviousData()**  `ck1.Checked = (Boolean)dt.Rows[i]["Active"]`

Comment: Rojalin, I've followed everything but im having error on `ck1.Checked = (Boolean)dt.Rows[i]["Active"];` it says _Specified cast is not valid._ hope we can sort this out thank you..

Comment: Use `Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i]["Active"]);` instead of that.