# C# - Keep the checkbox checked when gridview reloads when adding new row

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid-view wherein a user can add a new row when he wants to add new field, and will eventually be saved to a database.
I got 2 textboxes, and 1 checkbox.

Problem is, when the user clicks the "Add new row" the check on the checkbox(if the user ticked it) from the previous entry is removed.

*i.e on Fig1 I ticked on the Disabled checkbox for Tina before I clicked Add New Row, then its gone.*
[image]

On SetPreviousDataChild()is where im having errors, these two are suggested to keep the check on the checkbox but still im having error:

```
  Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]); //Error: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.

  ck1.Checked = (Boolean)dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]; //Error: Specified cast is not valid
```

Here is the original post where i got the code and help also: 
[How can I make Excel like grid in asp.net C# Webform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30273332/how-can-i-make-excel-like-grid-in-asp-net-c-sharp-webform/30274231?noredirect=1#comment69319030_30274231)

Complete C# code used :

```
private void bindgrdChild()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataRow dr = null;

    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ChildNo", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ChildName", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ChildBirthdate", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Disabled", typeof(bool)));

    dr = dt.NewRow();

    dr["ChildNo"] = 1;
    dr["ChildName"] = string.Empty;
    dr["ChildBirthdate"] = string.Empty;
    dr["Disabled"] = false;

    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    //Store the DataTable in ViewState
    ViewState["CurrentTable9"] = dt;
    gridChild.DataSource = dt;
    gridChild.DataBind();
}
protected void ButtonAddRowChild_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable9"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable9"];
        DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
        if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //extract the TextBox values


                TextBox tx1 = (TextBox)gridChild.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtChildName");
                TextBox tx2 = (TextBox)gridChild.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtChildBirth");
                CheckBox ck1 = (CheckBox)gridChild.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("cbChildDis");

                drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();

                drCurrentRow["ChildNo"] = i + 1;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["ChildName"] = tx1.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["ChildBirthdate"] = tx2.Text;
                dtCurrentTable.Rows[i - 1]["Disabled"] = ck1.Checked;

                rowIndex++;
            }
            dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
            ViewState["CurrentTable9"] = dtCurrentTable;

            gridChild.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
            gridChild.DataBind();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("ViewState is null");
    }

    SetPreviousDataChild();
}

private void SetPreviousDataChild()
{
    int rowIndex = 0;
    if (ViewState["CurrentTable9"] != null)
    {
        DataTable dt = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable9"];
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                TextBox tx1 = (TextBox)gridChild.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("txtChildName");
                TextBox tx2 = (TextBox)gridChild.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("txtChildBirth");
                CheckBox ck1 = (CheckBox)gridChild.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("cbChildDis");

                tx1.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ChildName"].ToString();
                tx2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["ChildBirthdate"].ToString();
//Here is where im having errors, these two are suggested to keep the check on the checkbox but still im having error
                Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]); //Error: Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.
                ck1.Checked = (Boolean)dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]; //Error: Specified cast is not valid


                    rowIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Question for you... when you do the .FindControl("cbChildDis"); is the ck1 null or does it actually find the checkbox control?

Comment: Do you want the checkbox checked when adding on the page and the already checked checkbox should not affected? Correct?

Comment: @Gwasshoppa It should find the checkbox control. The `private void SetPreviousDataChild()` is made so that the previous data on the txtboxes and checkbox will be kept when the gridview reloads when adding new row. If the user ticked on the checkbox before adding new field, the checkbox on the previous field should still be checked. But in my case it doesnt..

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq No, the checkbox should be null when adding a new row. And YES the previous checkbox should not be affected (whether its checked or not) when adding a new row. I added a picture on the question hope it may help! Thanks

Comment: the checkbox should be null - means not checked?

Comment: @MohamedThaufeeq that's correct. Initially it should not be checked.

Answer (score 0):

> Problem is, when the user clicks the "Add new row" the check on the
>   checkbox(if the user ticked it) from the previous entry is removed.

So concept of ***add new row*** is like it will create one new row in `DataTable` with **null**.

```
drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
drCurrentRow["ChildNo"] = i + 1;
```

These line of code is helping creating new row in DataTable , here value for each column expect first column is null but in case of checkbox we need one Boolean value. So solution is to create a column with true or false value as follow:

```
drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
 drCurrentRow["ChildNo"] = i + 1;
 drCurrentRow["Disabled"] = false;
```

Then you cloud use `Convert.ToBoolean` or `(bool)dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]` will work.

Comment: So  I didnt changed anything in the **bindgrid**, and in **addnewrow** I changed it to: `drCurrentRow["Disabled"] = false;` ,and in **SetPreviousData** I used:  `ck1.Checked = (bool)dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"];` and `ck1.Checked = Convert.ToBoolean(dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]);` im not getting error anymore, but its still not working :( The check on the previous row still not being kept when I add a new row..

Comment: Are you Sure that your `cells[2]` position contain Checkbox? Debug and check that what is value for `dt.Rows[i]["Disabled"]`.